magento cloud version upgrade to 2.4.7 completed but getting failed to load component error on checkout page for all custom modules
magento cloud version upgrade to 2.4.7 completed but getting failed to load component error on checkout page for all custom modules.
there are lots of error related to system upgrade / compatibility with PHP 8.2 / 8.3 version all fixed now component error on most of the custom modules as well as magento core modules is coming on checkout page not able to load the page due to this error.
any help / input much much appreciated thanks..............................................................................................................................................

